# How can I use nested evaluate function in excel

Tags: excel, evaluate

Is it possible to create a new Name in 'Name Manager' and Refer to - evaluate a cell that has a function in it but the function itself contains one or more variable that is also defined as Name in 'Name Manager' using evaluate function?
I tried but it gave me a '#Value!' warning.

Lets say there are two function: x = 1 + 1; and y = x + 1.
And I want to get result x and y.
So I put 1+1 in cell A1, and then go to Name Manager and create a Name called x and refer to: =if(NOW(), evaluate(A1)). and then go to cell B1 and type in =x and it shows the result of 2. Ok, it works for x.
So then I put x+1 in cell A2 and then go to Name Manager and create a Name called y and refer to =if(NOW(), evaluate(A2)). and then go to cell B2 and type in =y but it shows #VALUE! error

I expect it will give me the result of 3. Does anyone what cause this error and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to use EVALUATE()? for your example defining Namexp1=1+1 and Namexp2=namexp1+1 works ok. (There are a number of bugs/quirks with the old XLM EVALUATE function)

Comment: Hi Charles, the functions above are just examples to make it easier to understand. In fact 1+1 is other function that contains variables that defined in Name Manger too. At the beginning I thought it was because it was not allowed to use evaluate more than once. But then I tried the following for y and it worked. =if(Now(),evaluate((evaluate(A1)+1))). So I cannot think of any reasons why my original method didn't work. (I need to use variable x in other functions too)

Comment: EVALUATE has a lot of limitations: you may have hit one of them. You still have not explained why you need to use Evaluate. BTW You can nest Names up to something like 64 levels. But a circular chain of name references (NameA refers to NameB which refers to NameA) causes Excel to crash with a stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you didn't lock your cell references. Everything works fine if your named ranges contain absolute references (i.e. with `$` sign):

[image]

However, if you're working with relative references and you created your `y` value while having a cell in row 1 selected, then - once you move to cell `B2` - your relative reference will shift to row 3. As cell `A3` is empty, the result is a `#VALUE!` error message.

In other words, if you have cell `B1` selected while creating a named range with `A2` relative reference, then it will shift to cell `A3` once you select cell `B2`.

Screenshot #1 when having cell `B1` selected:

[image]

Screenshot #2 when having cell `B2` selected:

[image]